# PHP syntax error - SELECT WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an error with PHP SELECT WHERE code - which should be simple, but I have made no progress. 
The code works with `SELECT FROM` line, but not with the SELECT FROM WHERE `line. 
I have spent a few hours with no luck.
I have tried different syntax combinations with no progress.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer_crm` WHERE `sales_agent` = '$username'";

    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer_crm`"; /* this works*/
```

Comment: How does it not work? What do you expect? What do you get? Have you verified `$username` has a valid value that you are expecting? Have you run this query in a tool like PHPMyAdmin to see if the query works?

Comment: I get 0 results with the SELECT * WHERE and all of the results with the SELECT *.

Comment: Note: Use prepared statements

Comment: Is there a record in your database that meets the given dependency?

Comment: echo the `$sql`, and check if it's a valid query.

Comment: Yes there is a record. The line above the SELECT FROM is in fact an echo of the variable and it does display the correct result.

Comment: Guess you are a lover of SQL injection

Comment: use `print_r($sql)` or `var_dump($sql)` and update question with outpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you set a default character encoding, you can use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to avoid SQL Injections. However, the comment to use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) is really the best advice here.

However, with mysqli_real_escape_string your SQL should work like that:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `customer_crm` WHERE `sales_agent` = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username).'"';
```

Comment: Do you think that injections are the root problem? If yes, can you tell us why?

Comment: On the paper, his SQL should actually work - but it's vulnerable, so yes that's an issue. But the root problem, if I'm not overseeing anything here is not the statement itself.. Wasn't sure if you can escape strings with ' in SQL, but just tried that out and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I am not looking for a solution to injection issues, but rather a solution to the syntax issue please. These are some of the statements I have tried. The 2nd one works.//$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer_crm` WHERE `sales_agent` = '$username'";
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer_crm`";
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer_crm` WHERE `sales_agent` = ".$username;
//$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `customer_crm` WHERE `sales_agent` = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username).'"';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_crm WHERE sales_agent = '".$username."'";

Comment: Your statement isn't wrong. The second statement is just selecting all entries from the database while - that's at least my guess - the where clause is not producing any match. And you should really care about injection issues, at least if users have access to your program. However, what's the value of $username? Is there any entry for this username in the col sales_agent?

Answer (score -3):

You can even try this query

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer_crm` WHERE `sales_agent` = '".$username."'";

Comment: What does this change? The generated query will be the same one as in the original code